# RTKQ Mutation stuck in pending despite 204 returning from server

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

My mutation is forever stuck in pending despite a 204 response from the server. I am unable to make a response to success or failure because of this.

My code looks something like this:

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASE_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder: any) => ({
    updatePost: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, body }) => ({
        url: `${UPDATE_POST_URL}/${id}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

```
server.put('/UPDATE_POST_URL/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    params: { id },
    body,
  } = req;

  // Updates database
  // 204 status returned
  res.status(204);
  next();
});
```

When I call updatePost, I expected the mutation to be fulfilled or rejected, but it's stuck in pending mode. Have tried for most success codes and all manage to be fulfilled except for 204 and 205. Is this the expected behaviour for redux toolkit? I'm wondering if its expecting data to be returned from the server, but 204 is 'no-content'?

Comment: I think there's a way to customize which codes are considered success vs error.  But that doesn't seem to be the whole story -- if it was considering 204 as an error than you should get `rejected` not `pending`.

Comment: [Anything 2xx is a success](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#handling-non-standard-response-status-codes).  Try putting in a [`timeout`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#adding-a-custom-timeout-to-requests) and see if that's the issue.

Comment: If you continue having this problem, please create a reproduction and open an issue - but the reproduction is really required for problems like this.